# npm install laravel-mix failing on ubuntu - postinstall fail on gifsicle

Tags: ubuntu, npm, ubuntu-16.04, laravel-mix

I am working on configuring a live web server that requires running `npm run production` as a post deploy script. In order to successfully run this command, I need to successfully install laravel-mix. Upon running the below install command for laravel mix, I am getting a postinstall error that I am unable to resolve. This is a true blocker for me. I appreciate any suggestions on how to resolve.

```
sudo npm i laravel-mix

> gifsicle@3.0.4 postinstall /my/path/node_modules/gifsicle
> node lib/install.js

module.js:545
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '/my/path/node_modules/gifsicle/lib/install.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:543:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:470:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:690:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:194:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:666:3
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.1.3 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! gifsicle@3.0.4 postinstall: `node lib/install.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the gifsicle@3.0.4 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/ubuntu/.npm/_logs/2018-03-10T16_22_00_506Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
sudo rm -rf node_modules/
npm install
```

And let me know if this works.